# MMSE for channel estimation

Tags: signal-detection, channel-estimation

I am learning about the MMSE detector and how to implement it.

I looked at some example codes on the Internet but many of them directly use the perfect channel when calculating the MMSE estimated channel. For examples this one: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46856-channel-estimation-using-ls-and-mmse-estimators

I am quite confuse as if we know the perfect channel already, why do we need to use MMSE to estimate the channel?

It would be great if you can help me to explain this and provide references if any.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The internet is a terrible place to learn stuff like this. I recommend A. Schwarzinger, "DSP for modern communication systems" and R. Heath's "Introduction to wireless communications". Both cover this topic very well.